# Thread safety while sharing a reference between POSIX threads in OCaml

Tags: thread-safety, ocaml

A primitive way to have two threads share a state with type `int ref` in OCaml is:

```
let add i x =
    x := !x + i;
    Printf.printf "add %d: x is now %d\n" i !x;
    flush stdout

let rec run f x d =
    f x;
    Thread.delay d;
    run f x d

let _ =
    let x = ref 0 in
    ignore(Thread.create (run (add 1) x) 0.2);
    run (add 10) x 0.1
```

Function `add` just adds i to the integer in the reference x. Function `run` simply keeps applying f to the same argument x with delays of d between each application. The main function starts with 0 as the integer in the reference and invokes the run function in parallel with different arguments: (1) adding 1 and delaying 0.2s between calls; (2) adding 10 and delaying 0.1s between calls.

The output of running this program was:

```
add 10: x is now 10
add 1: x is now 11
add 10: x is now 21
add 10: x is now 31
add 1: x is now 32
add 10: x is now 42
add 10: x is now 52
add 1: x is now 53
add 10: x is now 63
add 10: x is now 73
add 1: x is now 74
add 10: x is now 84
add 10: x is now 94
add 1: x is now 95
[...]
```

It's easy to see that the contents of the reference are shared between threads.

I have used this construction in a case where the first `run` function was performing numerical calculations and the other `run` function was plotting the numbers calculated in the first thread. It worked well. In that case one of the threads was writing to the state but the other one was only reading. In the example coded above both threads write to the state which I think can be problematic, but I don't exactly know why.

### My Question

My questions about this are:

(1) Is this construction unsafe? If so, do you have an example where it can go wrong?
(2) Do you know of a better construction to achieve the same goal? Should I use some kind of locks or signals?

Thanks in advance for any help!

All the best,
Surikator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not safe. You have a race condition, the code works because of your particular timings and because the `add` function relies on the way the scheduler is implemented (which is subject to change).

What you need to remember is that conceptually your thread can be suspended at any time. Suppose the thread is suspended after the access to `!x`, or after the computation `(!x+1)` or between the assignment and the `printf`. If the other thread chimes in and executes the whole function before the suspended one is allowed to proceed, the result will be wrong.

One way to show the problem is to replace the add function by :

```
let add i x =
    x := !x + i;
    for i = 1 to Random.int 1000 do ignore (Unix.getaddrinfo "localhost" "" []) done;
    Printf.printf "add %d: x is now %d\n" i !x;
    flush stdout
```

(A simpler way is to insert a random `Thread.delay` between the assignement and the printf, but with the above you can see that a "regular" computation can bring in the problem)

Here's the result on my machine :

```
> ./test.native 
add 10: x is now 11
add 1: x is now 11
add 10: x is now 21
add 1: x is now 32
add 10: x is now 32
add 1: x is now 43
```

You need to ensure that the addition, the assignement and the `printf` are executed "atomically" by a thread ("atomically" in the sense that if a thread in suspended in this body of code no one should be allowed to enter it). One way of doing
that is to use a mutex :

```
let add =
  let m = Mutex.create () in
  fun i x ->
    Mutex.lock m;
    try
      x := !x + i;
      for i = 1 to Random.int 1000 do ignore (Unix.getaddrinfo "localhost" "" []) done;
      Printf.printf "add %d: x is now %d\n" i !x;
      flush stdout;
      Mutex.unlock m;
    with e -> Mutex.unlock m; raise e
```

Note that this works for the example you give but it assumes that only `add` modifies `x`. For more on the subject I recommend you to read :

http://ocamlunix.forge.ocamlcore.org/threads.html

and in particular :

http://ocamlunix.forge.ocamlcore.org/threads.html#htoc64

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Nice example to prove unsafety. I'll make sure I use Mutex in all such cases. Quick question: if only one thread writes and all others simply read are we safe without locks?

Comment: Yes, but you should try to convince yourself why this is indeed the case. Imagine all the different thread suspension that may happen to a reading and a writing thread concurrently accessing the ref. Reading the first example of the second link I gave you may help. Concurency is hard don't trust what I say.

Comment: I am convinced. I am aware of thread safety issues, just not on OCaml. I had never used the Mutex module. And I didn't even know I could share a reference between threads in OCaml as it's one of those typically imperative things where all kinds of things can go wrong. The example you mention also has read and write on multiple threads, so it doesn't solve the last question on my previous comment. But I believe that if only one thread writes, we can't get wrong results as far as thread-safety is concerned. Thanks a lot for the help!